# How to support .dcm image format file for uploading in an article?

Tags: 7, nodes, media, files

I want to upload .dcm image format file into Drupal7 article, but it's not allowed.

Suggestions about how to get this to work?

Comment: What kind of field is it?

Comment: This is an image field

Comment: .DCM files are not recognised by any browser as an image, so they can't and won't be displayed as such. The image field rightly doesn't allow you to upload a non-image file as an image, as it would be considered a bug. There's nothing you can do to 'fix' this I'm afraid, short of convincing the major browser vendors to implement the feature.

Comment: It is still a relevant question. For example, several browsers have some support for svg files, but Drupal doesn't allow that extension either.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to allow image extension that cannot commonly displayed by a browser. You would have to use a filefield instead.

This has been discussed at:

https://drupal.org/node/1081060

https://drupal.org/node/1014816

And for D6 at:

https://drupal.org/node/515152

Comment: All above urls are not working, please check. Yes, i hav got these urls by google search, but they are not working.

Comment: Hmm, the urls are working for me in different browsers. Do not understand why they are not working for you.

Comment: I have tried them on chrome, mozila, ie but still these urls are not working...

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you getting to the host drupal.org but not to the individual pages, and get an error code? Are you having issues with https? Are you not finding the host?

Comment: drupal.org is working, we can download any module... but not able to see these page.. we are getting error Sorry, 122.162.150.42 has been greylisted by http:BL.
You may try whitelisting on https://drupal.org/httpbl/whitelist.

Comment: This means that drupal.org got spammed from a computer with your ip address, apparently a common problem with certain ISPs. Did you try whitelisting - as the message suggested? Or anonymous browsing to appear having a different IP address (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_web_browsing), for example using http://www.ninjaproxy.eu/? Other remedies have been discussed at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10073/how-do-i-access-drupal-org-after-i-got-my-ip-banned.

Answer (score 0):

You can set allowed file types at the field settings page of that image field.

Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/field_image` and add the file extension to the comma separated list of allowed file types.

Comment: I have do that. But still its not include .dcm extension.

Comment: This approach works for file fields. For image fields, Drupal restricts extensions to a few that can get displayed in most browsers. Unfortunately, Drupal 7 doesn't issue a warning when the administrator adds an additional extension to the form quoted above.